# Error: "ANN Visualizer: Layer not supported for visualizing" in the function ann_viz()

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

So I am using the ann_visualizer for showing my keras model neural network graphically. The model works properly, but it gives this error whenever I try to visualize it via ann_viz().

"**ValueError: ANN Visualizer: Layer not supported for visualizing**"

I searched the internet but couldn't find a valid solution.
this is the neural network model code

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=keras.activations.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=keras.activations.softmax))


model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(train_data, train_lables, epochs=10)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_lables)
```

And this is the ann_viz() function call

```
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz

ann_viz(model, title="Model")
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Can you check removing the Flatten() layer. Reshape the input yourself before passing to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got the same error but was able to resolve by removing the Flatten() layer.

```
#Flatten the input 
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 28*28)

model = keras.Sequential()

#added flat input shape
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(28*28,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=keras.activations.softmax))

model.compile(
optimizer="adam",
loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
metrics=["accuracy"]
)

#now you can call the ann_viz
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz
ann_viz(model, title="Model")
```

Basically, I Flattened the input, removed the Flatten layer and added the flat input shape in the next layer.
Don't know the exact reason though.

Comment: The same error was caused by the Rescaling layer, so I removed it for visualizing the network.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by changing this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential([
    Dense(6, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="sigmoid"),
    Dense(3, activation="sigmoid"),
    Dense(1, activation="linear")])
```

To:

```
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(6, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="sigmoid"),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="sigmoid"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")])
```